# Create virtual machine with vmrun?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, unix, vmware

I am using vmware's workstation pro, and I need to be able to manage multiple virtual machines remotely. Is it possible to use vmrun to create a virtual machine? Or can it only control already created machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have VMware Workstation here and several Virtual Machines here that I created.

> Is it possible to use vmrun to create a virtual machine? Or can it
> only control already created machines?

VMrun is used to manage machines. You cannot create a machine with VMrun.

[VMrun Usage](https://vi-toolkit.com/wiki/index.php/Vmrun)

**Things you can do:**

Power off the VM.

Suspend the VM.

Create a snapshot.

Revert to a snapshot (need to verify).

Pause and unpause the VM.

Power on the VM using the 'gui' option.

Perform guest operations (runProgramInGuest,    listDirectoryInGuest, etc.).

Start and stop recording.

Mount the Tools installer.

Run any vProbes commands.

Change the shared folder settings (add, remove, enable) of a running VM.

**Things you cannot do:**

Upgrade the VM's virtual hardware.

Power on the VM using the 'nogui' option.

Change the shared folder settings (add, remove, enable) of a powered off or suspended VM.

**Creating a Virtual Machine:**

You can normally create a virtual machine by downloading the installer ISO file and then create the machine in VMware, File, New Machine and follow the steps.

I created Kali and Ubuntu this way. I created Windows 7 and prior Windows machines from the DVD because I have the DVDs.

I hope this assists you.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create a vm from the CLI?

Comment: To get a virtual machine you need to obtain one (pre-packaged virtual machines are available) or install a virtual machine from the installation disk. I have installed my virtual machines the latter way except I downloaded Kioptrix (a Linux vm).  I added this to my answer to help you.

Comment: Yes, I am more concerned with the creation of a vm from a CLI. Do you know if I can copy and paste the directory of a pre-existing vm and just change the file names?

Comment: You can change the file name of a Virtual Machine in the Machine Settings. In VMware you can use the VM tab and Settings within that to change the file name . I have done this before. You can see if this might be done with the vmrun Guest commands.

Comment: So I can copy the contents of a vm directory and create a new vm from that? I am trying to avoid using the UI as this is a remote server

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that. If you move and rename a machine, VMware will ask you if you Moved or Copied the machine. Answer as appropriate.

Comment: FYI you can now power on a VM without a GUI using vmrun: `vmrun start name.vmwarevm nogui`